# Send keystroke to other control

Tags: c#, forwarding, keystroke

Easy one for you guys.

I have a textbox on top of a listbox.

The textbox is use to filter ther data in the listbox.

So... When the user type in the textbox, I would like to "trap" the down/up/pagedown/pageup keystrokes and fowarding them to the listbox.

I know I could use the Win32 API and send the WM_KeyDown message. But there's must be some .NET way to do this.

Comment: Selected best answer it not the best solution in all situations ! See SendMessage() answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SendKeys.Send() Method.

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Focus();
            SendKeys.Send(e.KeyChar.ToString());
        }
```

Here is code through which you can select a list item.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            textBox1.AutoCompleteSource=AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            string[] ar = (string[])(listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()).ToArray<string>();
            textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(ar);
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Text  = textBox1.Text;
        }
```

Comment: How do I tell SendKeys.Send to send the keystroke to the listbox control?

Comment: And if I want the focus to stay in the textbox, I do textbox.focus() right after?

Weird that sendkey don't have an overload to pass a control to it...

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PageUp || e.KeyCode == Keys.PageDown || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            // Setting e.IsInputKey to true will allow the KeyDown event to trigger.
            // See "Remarks" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx
            e.IsInputKey = true;
        }
    }

    private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string send = "";
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PageUp)
        {
            send = "PGUP";
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PageDown)
        {
            send = "PGDN";
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            send = "UP";
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            send = "DOWN";
        }
        if (send != "")
        {
            // We must focus the control we want to send keys to and use braces for special keys.
            // For a list of all special keys, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx.
            listBox.Focus();
            SendKeys.SendWait("{" + send + "}");
            textBox.Focus();
            // We must mark the key down event as being handled if we don't want the sent navigation keys to apply to this control also.
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data Binding

```
            listBox1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", textBox1, "Text", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged).
            Format += (sender, e) =>
            {
                e.Value = _strings.FindAll(s => s.StartsWith((string) e.Value));
            };
```

Comment: Data binding to send a keystroke to another control??

Comment: No, to filter ther data in the list box. If you bind Text property of the textbox to DataSource property of the listbox and use DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged you can achieve this.

Comment: Oh... I think I can't do this. Because the listbox items are already filled with a List<> binded to the datasource property...

Comment: You need to somehow filter the listbox content in the Format event for the binding.

Answer (score 0):

In our wpf app we have a textbox that filters a listbox, we use the previewkeyup event.  Inside the code, we can check what key was pressed (don't have my code in front of me, it's something like e.Key == Key.UpArrow, either way there's a built in class in C# for this).  If it's one of the hot keys, we manipulate the user control accordingly.

For the listbox we tossed it into a user control and implemented an interface, called it NavigateableListbox or something like that, forced it to implement MoveUp(), MoveDown(), PageUp(), PageDown() etc so the textbox event just says if e.Key = Key.UpArrow { mylistbox.MoveUp() }

Answer (score 0):

`SendKeys.Send()` method does'nt work in all situations because `Send()` method can be addressed to another Control !

In 2020, the best solution to be sure at 100% is to use SendMessage() function.

In VB.Net, I use following code

```
Public Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll"
    ( ByVal hWnd As IntPtr
    , ByVal wMsg As Int32
    , ByVal wParam As Int32
    , ByVal s As Int32
    ) As Int32

Private Const WM_CHAR As Int32 = &H102

SendMessage(txtInput.Handle, WM_CHAR, AscW(sValue.Chars(0)), 0)
```

Where `txtInput` is a sample `Textbox` control.

In my case, I click on html `<div>` element defined in a `WebView` control that changes color when I click on it or when mouse move over. When I click on this `<div>` a ScriptNotify() VB.Net method is called to enter some characters in `Textbox` using `SendMessage()` function.

In old solution, I think that sometimes, `WebView` gain focus before `SendKeys.Send()` method  is called so that propagated key is not send to `txtInput` Textbox.

You can use old solution, but be certain that one day, SendKeys.Send() function will send what you want to another Handle.