# How Do I Emulate a Keystroke In C# WPF Application?

Tags: c#, wpf

Inside the application there is an if statement. It checks a string variable kai if the variable equals to 1 i want it to react as if i pressed the right arrow on my keyboard. Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: The same is also answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264227/send-keystroke-to-other-control

Comment: @TechnologyDigestified: Links in comments have this format: `[display text](url)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe like this:

```
SendKey.Send({rigth});
```

set focus to the control you want to input before.
And you ave to declare

```
Using System.Windows.Form
```

Comment: What if i want to set focus to another active application? Any tips there?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you might want to think about using Commands for that. If you think about what you want to achieve it is to trigger something after the Key-Press. If you use a Command for that you can directly trigger it without going via the programmatic key pressing stuff. Also you can still trigger the command via a keypress (InputGesture).

You can find out more about Commands here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx